# Re-rendering link while login and logout in react.js

Tags: reactjs

While i am login! home,logout and other link is not visible until i refresh the component. in url redirect is properly working but Link of logout  is not showing after login and same logout . If need a more explaination please let me know[enter image description here][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHljf.png`here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHljf.png%60here) is the image so you can see the my home page where i login but link home, logout etc. is not visble. when refresh the console then link is showing

```
class TodoApp extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div id="div1" className='TodoApp'>
            <Router>
                <HeaderComponent />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={LoginComponent} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute path="/welcome/:name" component={WelcomComponent} />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute path="/todo" component={TodoComponent} />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute path="/logout" component={LogoutComponent} />
                    <Route component={ErrorComponent} />
                </Switch>
                <FooterComponent />
            </Router>

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

```
class HeaderComponent extends Component {
render() {

    return (
        <header>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div><a href="http://www.google.com" className="navbar-brand">Rahul</a></div>
                <ul className="navbar-nav">
                    {ApplicationServer.isUserLoggedIn() && <li><Link to="/welcome/Rahul">Home</Link></li>}
                    {ApplicationServer.isUserLoggedIn() && <li><Link to="/todo">Todos</Link></li>}
                </ul>
                <ul className="navbar-nav navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
                    {!ApplicationServer.isUserLoggedIn() && <li><Link  to="/login">Login</Link></li>}
                    {ApplicationServer.isUserLoggedIn() && <li><Link  to="/logout" onClick={ApplicationServer.logout}>LogOut</Link></li>}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>


    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that isUserLoggedIn() is invoked once on component load and never after since it does not know to update. You can create a helper function which is called when the user clicks on Login/Logout. It will check ApplicationServer.isUserLoggedIn() and set the result in the state of isLoggedIn. This way you can use `isLoggedIn && <li>` in your code and when state changes, component will automatically update and re-render

Comment: Tried set the result in the state of isLoggedIn  and also create a function where the state has been changed but is not working.

Comment: Did you add an onClick() call on Login and Logout that would trigger isUserLoggedIn() and change the state?

Comment: yes, but it didn't work, but i got the solution after continue trying. while calling the Headercomponent  i am use withRouter(HeaderComponent)  now i get the solution thanking for the help.